# How to Save Append type data from richTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to save data from richTextBox to existing file called **"data.rtf"** but problem is that it overwrites the file.

I am using this code:

```
richTextBox.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

I want to append Text

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you only want to append something to an existing RTF and not overwrite it?

Comment: yes exactly I want to append but it seems rtf doesn't support append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(FilePath))
 {
    writer.WriteLine(richTextBox1.text);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I really need this thing :)

Comment: Does this work with (a formatted) RichTextFormat? Or only with the inner (pure) text?

Comment: Alex it works only with the pure text without the format

Answer (score 1):

Try to store the previous data in a variable, later set  the richTextBox's data to previous + new and then call the SaveFile method.

Something like this

```
var olddata = DataFromExistingFile;
var newdata = old + RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText;
```

then

```
richTextBox.SaveFile(path, newdata);
```

Comment: It appears that indeed `RichTextBox` doesn't support appending to an existing file. This is probably due to a limitation in RTF. This is the more pragmatic approach but can be quite slow (relativly) comparing to just appending to an existing text file.

Comment: Old file contain 297104 characters it will increase at least up to 1 million characters. So is it safe and fast to store that amount of characters in a single variable?